# PS Scratch disk obsolete?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I have 16GB of RAM and I do not believe that I can saturate all that RAM. I am only dealing with 16MP+ photographs and I will not be opening 20+ images at a time.

From my understanding scratch disks are a must in the pre-64bit architecture days where only 2 gb of RAM can be used for PS, so if everything can be fitted into RAM then essentially the scratch disk is useless correct?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design. This question would have been better asked over at Super User, but since it has already been answered and accepted, I will leave it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You are correct.  Photoshop will not touch your scratch disk if it has enough memory.

Optimal memory settings are usually allocating around 70% of total ram to Photoshop.

> Photoshop Memory Usage setting Using 70% is the smart move until and
> unless tests show that more is faster.
>
> The operating system version, Photoshop version, other programs, etc,
> all influence whether too high a setting improves performance, or
> instead causes virtual memory paging and/or degrades the ability of
> the system to have enough spare memory for drive caching. It is a
> performance see-saw effect under some conditions.
> -- [Mac Performance Guide](http://macperformanceguide.com/OptimizingPhotoshopCS5-memory-pref.html)

Also to note is that Photoshop does not pre-allocate the memory. It only uses it if it needs it.

> Enough is enough
>
> Remember too that enough is enough— Photoshop will use what it needs,
> up to the limit set with this preference.
>
> Using a setting of 90% instead of 70% is meaningless when Photoshop
> really only needs and uses 40%. Photoshop will use what it needs up to
> the limit; it does not pre-allocate the memory, it’s simply a future
> limit when Photoshop is launched.